# composer gives false warning when run as a non-root user with setuid bit set

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, chown, setuid

I configured my php executable i.e /usr/local/bin/php with a `setuid` for user `deploy`. So that if any user calls that php binary it should be executed as `deploy` only. As you can see below php binary is chowned by a non-root user `deploy`. But when I execute php composer.phar as `root` why I am getting that warning `Do not run Composer as root/super user!` . I shouldn't get that warning as php binary is owned by `deploy` and setuid bit is set.

```
> ls -al /usr/local/bin/php
 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root     /usr/local/bin/php

> chown deploy:deploy /usr/local/bin/php 

> chmod u+s /usr/local/bin/php

> ls -al /usr/local/bin/php
 -rwsr-xr-x    1 deploy   deploy   /usr/local/bin/php

> ls -al composer.phar 
 -rwxr-xr-x    1 deploy   1000     composer.phar

> whoami 
 root

> php composer.phar -V
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Composer version 1.7.2 2018-08-16 16:57:12
```

However even if executing `php composer.phar install` as `root` the vendor dir created is owned by `deploy`.

Infact the composer process ignores the setuid bit but when it creates any file/dir it obey setuid.

I inserted below inside the composer.phar and get the right user `deploy` but with a warning `Don't call as root` . Is it an issue of composer ?

```
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
print $processUser['name'];
```

Comment: Basically for security reasons, so `scripts` or `plugins` can not be run as root: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I am already aware what you answered.

Comment: I read your question. "_But when I execute php composer.phar as root why I am getting that warning Do not run Composer as root/super user!_" You get that warning for said reasons. Don't run it as root then. You shouldn't login as root on linux system but instead login as your "regular" user and use `sudo` to execute commands that require root privileges (composer is NOT one of those programs that require root privileges)

Comment: @kerbholz I think still you are not getting my question. Do you know what is setuid? Note: Even if I call php as root but it is owned by another user `deploy` and a setuid bit is set for that user.

Comment: Does it change anything if you use `/usr/local/bin/php` instead if `php`?

Comment: @rob006 no it doesn't change anything. Get same warning. Also I can ensure you that correct php is getting called as `which php` displays /usr/local/bin/php

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an bug in composer https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7758#issuecomment-434308672